# how to update the local stored json file in asset folder via URL request in android

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to make a mobile application, the data i am using is a huge nested JSON object which is a live API on some website. Instead of calling URL request to get the data, i have downloaded the json file and stored it on my asset folder in android. As the data was so huge thats why I stored it locally in the asset folder to avoid a lag in a request. Problem is, i have stored it locally and if the data get updated in website it wont come up to me. i want to make some kind of a method where an app user can update the data itself.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output / tracebacks). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Files in assets are read only and hence not updatable.

Comment: For me it sounds like you want to have a local NoSQL database which automatically synchs with a remote backend.
A JSON file in the assets folder is the wrong approach for that.